# UIWebView pagination

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have a large html content to render in a UIWebView, I want to display the content in pages just like a book and the user uses buttons to navigate the pages. Is there any way to calculate the height of html content that fits in the webview without scrolling?

Answer (score 3):

If anyone comes around, in iOS7 and more you can just do :

```
self.webview.paginationBreakingMode = UIWebPaginationBreakingModePage;
self.webview.paginationMode = UIWebPaginationModeLeftToRight;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (id subview in self.webView.subviews) 
{
    if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
    {
        ((UIScrollView *)subview).pagingEnabled = YES;
        break;
    }
}
```